# Is it possible to link to a job in the bigquery console?

Tags: google-bigquery

If I execute a BigQuery job using the REST API (i.e. bigquery.googleapis.com) in the response I get back a selfLink that looks something like this:

`https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/my-project/jobs/job_0123456789ABCDEF?location=EU`

In the UI (ie.. console.cloud.google.com) I can see the very same job in the project's query history:

[image]

Is it possible to use the information within that API response and construct a URL that will allow a person to visit that URL in the browser and be taken directly to the information about that query in the UI? This would be really useful because we could log a message containing that URL so that anyone viewing the logs can see a user-friendly UI regarding that job.

I suspect the answer is "no" but just thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can share this link:

`https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?project=<my-project>j=<bq:<location>:<job_id>>&page=queryresults`

For example: https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?project=my-project&j=bq:US:2846160a-9a13-4192-9bff-e691ff2adab6&page=queryresults

If a user has BQ Job List permission in that project, then when they open up the link they will be be able to see the query that was run in the UI, along with the job information.

But they can't see the query results, which is intended behavior. Instead they will get a warning:

`Access Denied: User does not have permission to access results of another user's job.`

Comment: This might explain why I was asking, by the way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67110026/how-can-i-correctly-log-a-url-within-cloud-logging-without-an-ampersand-getting