# How can i correctly log a URL within Cloud Logging without an ampersand getting converted to unicode representation?

Tags: google-cloud-logging, google-workflows

*Not sure whether this I should have tagged this google-cloud-logging or google-workflows as I'm not sure whether the problem lies, so I tagged both.*

I have a Google Cloud Workflow (the workflow definition is provided below) that executes a BigQuery stored procedure via the [BigQuery jobs.insert](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/insert) REST API. I would like to log a message that provides a URL to that results of that job in the Google Cloud Console.

Thanks to the answer received at [Is it possible to link to a job in the bigquery console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67104653/is-it-possible-to-link-to-a-job-in-the-bigquery-console/67108721#67108721) I know I can construct a URL that takes me to the query result, it looks like this:

```
https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?project=<my-project>j=<bq:<location>:<job_id>>&page=queryresults
```

Hence I am logging a message from my Google Cloud Workflow to Google Cloud Logging containing that URL. Here is the portion of my workflow that does it:

```yaml
        - bq_job_get_post_completion:
            call: bqJobGet
            args:
                project_id: ${project_id}
                job_id: ${job_id}
            result: bq_job_get_response
        - set_job_completion_vars:
            assign:
                - jobCompletionStats:
                        jobId: ${job_id}
                        totalBytesBilled: ${bq_job_get_response.body.statistics.query.totalBytesBilled}
                        totalBytesProcessed: ${bq_job_get_response.body.statistics.query.totalBytesProcessed}
                        totalSlotMs: ${bq_job_get_response.body.statistics.query.totalSlotMs}
                        jobDetailsUrl: ${"https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?project=" + project_id + "&j=bq:EU:" + job_id + "&page=queryresults"}
```

Note the **jobDetailsUrl** part.

Unfortunately when this gets appears in cloud logging the URL looks like this:

`https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?project=my-redacted-project\u0026j=bq:EU:job_XXXXXX\u0026page=queryresults`

As you might be able to see, the ampersands have been replaced with **\u0026**. I understand why this is, 26 is the unicode character code for an ampersand...however the URL no-longer takes me direct to the correct result in the Google Cloud Console - essentially the pertinent information in the URL has been invalidated.

Can anyone advise how I can stop this from happening? I want the correct URL to appear in the cloud logging.

Here is the entirety of my workflow:

```yaml
main:
    steps:
        - call_subWorkflow:
            call: callBQStoredProc
            args:
                stored_proc_name: "mydataset.my-stored-procedure"
                project_id: my-redacted-project


#SUBWORKFLOWS
callBQStoredProc:
    params: [stored_proc_name, project_id, poll_wait_time_seconds: 5]
    steps:
        - init:
            assign:
                - job:
                        jobReference:
                            location: EU
                        configuration:
                            query:
                                useLegacySql: false
                                useQueryCache: false
                                query: ${"call " + stored_proc_name + "()"}
        - log_start:
            call: sys.log
            args:
                text: >
                    ${"Starting execution of bigquery stored procedure \"" + stored_proc_name + "\" using subworkflow executeBQStoredProc"}
                severity: INFO
        - postCallStoredProc:
            call: http.post
            args:
                url: ${"https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/" + project_id + "/jobs"}
                body: ${job}
                auth:
                    type: OAuth2
            result: bq_jobs_insert_response
        - set_job_id:
            assign:
                - job_id: ${bq_jobs_insert_response.body.jobReference.jobId}
        - bq_job_get:
            call: bqJobGet
            args:
                project_id: ${project_id}
                job_id: ${job_id}
            result: bq_job_get_response
        - set_job_vars:
            assign:
                - job_state: ${bq_job_get_response.body.status.state}
                - job_project: ${bq_job_get_response.body.jobReference.projectId}
        - log_job_state:
            call: sys.log
            args:
                text: >
                    ${"Job " + job_id + " in project " + job_project + " has state : " + job_state}
                severity: INFO
        - check_job_state:
            switch:
                - condition: ${job_state != "DONE"}
                  steps:
                    - wait_10s:
                        call: sys.sleep
                        args:
                            seconds: ${int(poll_wait_time_seconds)}
                        next: bq_job_get
        - bq_job_get_post_completion:
            call: bqJobGet
            args:
                project_id: ${project_id}
                job_id: ${job_id}
            result: bq_job_get_response
        - set_job_completion_vars:
            assign:
                - jobCompletionStats:
                        jobId: ${job_id}
                        totalBytesBilled: ${bq_job_get_response.body.statistics.query.totalBytesBilled}
                        totalBytesProcessed: ${bq_job_get_response.body.statistics.query.totalBytesProcessed}
                        totalSlotMs: ${bq_job_get_response.body.statistics.query.totalSlotMs}
                        jobDetailsUrl: ${"https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?project=" + project_id + "&j=bq:EU:" + job_id + "&page=queryresults"}
        - log_job_completion:
            call: sys.log
            args:
                text: ${jobCompletionStats}
                severity: INFO
        - bq_job_get_query_results:
            call: http.request
            args:
                url: ${"https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/" + project_id + "/queries/" + job_id}
                method: GET
                auth:
                    type: OAuth2
            result: bq_job_get_query_results_response
        - returnResult:
            return: ${bq_job_get_query_results_response.body}
bqJobGet:
    params: [project_id, job_id]
    steps:
        - bq_job_get:
            call: http.request
            args:
                url: ${"https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/" + project_id + "/jobs/" + job_id}
                method: GET
                auth:
                    type: OAuth2
            result: bq_job_get_response
        - returnResult:
            return: ${bq_job_get_response}
```

Comment: This is probably a silly question of me to ask but... have you tried escaping the characters in the string using "\"?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to log a map as text. In the documentation of the [sys.log](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/stdlib/sys/log) function there is also the option to log a json. You simply need to replace 'text' with 'json' like this:

```
- log_job_completion:
    call: sys.log
    args:
        json: ${jobCompletionStats}
        severity: INFO
```

Another option would be to log the url in an own logging step like this:

```
- log_job_completion_details_url:
    call: sys.log
    args:
        text: ${jobCompletionStats.jobDetailsUrl}
        severity: INFO
```

Hope that gives you the desired output.