# Google BigQuery - Is it possible to link to a table in the bigquery console?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

If I have a table I want to link to, is it possible to generate a link to the table schema page in the UI (ie. console.cloud.google.com)?

I saw in [this question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67104653/is-it-possible-to-link-to-a-job-in-the-bigquery-console) you can link to a job but I want to link to a table instead so something along the lines of `https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?project=<my-project>&dataset=...` would be ideal so I could construct the link using just my project, dataset, and table names.

Comment: By opening the table schema page in the BQ UI, You can get the URL of the table ie. from the url bar of your browser. Let me know if this helps, if not kindly mention your use case to proceed.

Comment: Couldn't find official document but you might want to try this URL `https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?project=[PROJECT_ID]&ws=!1m5!1m4!4m3!1s[PROJECT_ID]!2s[DATASET_NAME]!3s[TABLE_NAME]`

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any public documentation to this requirement, however as mentioned by @Arpita and @Jiho, to get the URL of the dataset or the table you can try opening the table schema page in the BigQuery User Interface and from the URL bar of your browser you'll be able to get the selected table URL which is in the format:

```
https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?project=[PROJECT_ID]&ws=!1m5!1m4!4m3!1s[PROJECT_ID]!2s[DATASET_NAME]!3s[TABLE_NAME]
```